# Array Index out of range while retrieving string from TRIE data structure?

Tags: java, data-structures, trie

I am storing string and its frequencies in TRIE data structure

```
hello 100
world 5000
good 2000
bad 9000
```

Below is my `TrieImpl` class

```
public class TrieImpl {

    //root node
    private TrieNode r;

    public TrieImpl() {
        r = new TrieNode();
    }

    public int find(String word) {
        return r.getFreq(word);
    }

    public void insert(String word, int freq) {
        r.insert(word, freq);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return r.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TrieImpl t = new TrieImpl();

        System.out.println("Testing some strings");
        // storing strings and its frequencies
        t.insert("HELLO", 10);
        t.insert("WORLD", 20);

        System.out.println(t.find("HELLO"));
        System.out.println(t.find("HELLO1")); // this line throws Array Index Out of Range
    }
}
```

And below is my `TrieNode class` -

```
public class TrieNode {

    // make child nodes
    private TrieNode[] c;
    // flag for end of word
    private boolean flag = false;
    // stores frequency if flag is set
    private int frequency;

    public TrieNode() {
        c = new TrieNode[26];
    }

    protected void insert(String word, int frequency) {
        int val = word.charAt(0) - 64;

        // if the value of the child node at val is null, make a new node
        // there to represent the letter
        if (c[val] == null) {
            c[val] = new TrieNode();
        }

        // if the value of the child node at val is null, make a new nod
        if (word.length() > 1) {
            c[val].insert(word.substring(1), frequency);
        } else {
            c[val].flag = true;
            c[val].frequency = frequency;
        }
    }


    public int getFreq(String word) {
        int val = word.charAt(0) - 64;
        if (word.length() > 1) {
            return c[val].getFreq(word.substring(1));
        } else if (c[val].flag == true && word.length() == 1) {
            return c[val].frequency;
        } else
            return -1;
    }


    public String toString() {
    return c.toString();
    }
}
```

I am able to insert string and its frequencies in TRIE and also able to lookup frequencies for a give string which is already present. Now the issue which I am facing is - If I am looking up forr a string which is not there in the TRIE, it throws `Arrays Index Out of Range` error.

If you see my above `TrieImpl` class, I am searching for string `HELLO1` which is not there in TRIE, so for that case, it throws out ArrayIndex out of range.

Any thoughts how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply check if `val`'s going to be out of range in your `getFreq` function.

You probably also need to check if there's actually an element at the target index (i.e. it's not `null`).

Also, as pointed out in the other answer, you're passing an 'invalid' string to your function, because `1` results in a negative `val` value / index - either you should avoid doing this, or you could add that check to your function as well.

```
public int getFreq(String word) {
  int val = word.charAt(0) - 64;
  if (val < 0 || val >= c.length || c[val] == null)
    return -1;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks so how my full function will look like? I just need to add that if check at the top of my method?

Comment: Yes, you just need to add the check to the top of your method.

Comment: Thanks. That issue got fixed. One more quick question, It's not related to this but it is same Array Index Out  of Bound Exception. Whenever I am inserting lower caps `hello` it throws me `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at `if (c[val] == null) {` but if I insert all upper caps `HELLO` it works fine. Any thoughts what could be the reason?

Comment: Your array is only 26 long. Look at [a Unicode table](http://unicode-table.com/en/) and you'll see that lowercase letters appear after uppercase letters, with some other characters in between. So you'll need to increase the size if you want to cater for both (or handle them separately if you want it to be case insensitive). Also, you should probably `-65`, not `-64` (or, even better, `-'A'`), as to let `A` be `0`, not `1`.

Comment: Thanks Duke. I need to handle both the cases so what size I should use here just to make everything going smoothly? And also I have change to -65 instead  of -64.

Comment: Well, 26 for uppercase, 6 character in between (as per the unicode table) and 26 for lowercase, so `26+26+6=58`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50815/discussion-between-user2809564-and-dukeling)

Answer (score 1):

You are using: `t.find("HELLO1")`, which will be passed to your `getFreq()` function.

it will proceed calling `getFreq()` with `ELLO1`, `LLO1`, `LO1`, `O1`

At the point, when the implementation retries it with only word `1` due due your recursive aproach, it will result in `int val = word.charAt(0) - 64; // 49-64` and thats a value of `val = -15` - and that's not a valid array index.

Comment: Aaahh.. Thanks for the help. So how my method should look like in general?

Comment: @dognose word.charAt(0) for '1' will be 49 right? The ASCII value?